# inserting list in database in single column in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, list, sqlite

i have variable varlist which have the list elements and want to insert it in my db
there are two columns sess_id which is autoincrement and list where i want to store the data
when i do this:

```
    varlist=["easy"]
    cursor_one.execute("insert into data (list) values(%s)", varlist)
    conn.commit()
```

my data is inserted properly, but if i increase the no. of element in varlist:

```
    varlist=["easy","hard","medium"]
    cursor_one.execute("insert into data (list) values(%s)", varlist)
    conn.commit()
```

i come accross this error:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\xampp\htdocs\eclipse_workspace\Project\check.py", line 19, in 
    <module>
     cursor_one.execute("insert into data (list) values(%s)", database_list)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 
     553, in execute
     "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
     mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used 
     in the SQL statement
```

this is my whole code

```
    import mysql.connector
     conn= mysql.connector.connect
    (user="root",password="",host="localhost",database="videojs")

    varlist=['easy','hard']

    cursor_one.execute("insert into data (list) values(%s)", varlist)
    conn.commit()
```

please help me....

Comment: Why is this tagged as MySQL and Sqlite3? They are fundamentally different.

Comment: ^ Also, I kinda get the feeling this was already asked yesterday.

Comment: cause im inserting in mysql db and importing sqlite 3 in python

Comment: cant you please help me...

Comment: Well that still doesn't make sense to me. Why are you using two databases? Anyway, you could try `placeholders = ['%s' for x in range(len(varlist))]` and then `cursor_one.execute("insert into data (list) values({})".format(placeholders), varlist)`. But that's perhaps not the cleanest code and I don't know whether you need `%s` or `?` as a placeholder because you're not specific on the technology you're using.

Comment: Sorry, `.format(', '.join(placeholders))`.

Comment: no im using a single database and a table data with two columns in it.

Comment: join in replacment of format????

Comment: ohk sorry lemme try got your point

Comment: sir tried both placeholders but still the same error **"Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement"** .

Comment: Please show the exact statement used. I'm not sure that error makes sense if you translated my comment properly. You can edit it into your question to make it easier to read.

Comment: sir updated and same error when applied your query...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on what you are trying to accomplish.  If you are trying to insert the entire list into one "cell" in the database,  you'll need to convert the list to a string representation:

```
    import pickle

    varlist=["easy","hard","medium"]
    cursor_one.execute("insert into data (list) values(%s)", pickle.dumps(varlist))
    conn.commit()
```

If however, you are trying to put each entry in the list into its own row in the database, you will need to iterate through the list inserting a row for each entry:

```
    varlist=["easy","hard","medium"]
    for var in varlist: 
        cursor_one.execute("insert into data (list) values(%s)", var)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: yes entire list in one cell ...well sir your program resulted in following:........ AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_list_to_mysql'.......TypeError: Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type.......    "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Comment: try using repr() instead, like I have updated the example to show.

Comment: raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1

Comment: What database are you using? you tagged the question with Mysql and sqlite3, now you are referring to MariaDB.  Try pickling your info: import pickle; pickle.dumps(varlist) instead of repr(varlist)